# Angular combine ngIf and EventEmitter creates multiple calls

Tags: angular, eventemitter

In my application I noticed unexpected behavior. Probably I made a mistake but I don't know where.

Scenario: I have two components: parent and child. 
Parent template contains '*ngIf' condition and can display or not child. 
Parent and child shares service. Child subscribes event. Parent emits event.

After series of below steps: 
1. hide child
2. show child
3. trigger event

event is handle n+1 times. Where n is number of trials. 
Plunk for this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/TWHO6PPYa55QGoHDXdFN

Parent component template:

```
<div *ngIf="show">
  <my-child-app></my-child-app>
</div>
```

Parent relevant class code:

```
show:boolean = true;
  constructor(private service: AppService) {
  }

  changeShow(){
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  emitSome(){
    this.service.appEvent.emit("abc");
  }
```

Child relevant part of code:

```
 constructor(private service: AppService) {
    this.service.appEvent.subscribe((s: string) => console.log(s));
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clean up the subscription when the component is destroyed. Every time the child is shown because of the `ngIf` it calls the constructor of the child which re-subscribes to the Emitter. Modify your code to match the following:

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private eventSubscription;

    constructor(private service: AppService) {
        this.eventSubscription = this.service.appEvent
                                             .subscribe((s: string) => console.log(s));
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```